# How can I exclude a folder from search results in Plone?

Tags: plone

I would like to mark a folder as 'its content will be excluded from the search form'

Visitors will not find it with the search engine even if it visible throw direct link.
I already know the end date can help me to achieve this, but in some case, I just would like to have valide content just excluded not just archived.

I want the content to be findeable throw other search forms like the rich text editor  or the related items.

So the content need to be indexed in the portal_catalog SearcheableText, but excluded from search results because it is in this folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This topic was recently discussed in plone-users list:

http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/How-to-hide-pages-from-search-results-td6271253.html

Comment: To sum up the thread: We need to cutomize the search process to achieve this.You have created an add-on called collective.hiddencontent which provide a new flag on every content ala 'exclude from nav'.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that it is quite simple to do without an add-on by setting the expiration date to a past date and then customizing the **Access inactive portal content** permission to allow content editors to see inactive content.